# C++ Boost asio get data size?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using the boost asio library to read some data using tcp. After using `a.accept(*sock);`, how to get the size of the 1st packet the client will send?

I use `(sock->remote_endpoint().address()).to_string()` to get the IP address of the user, so I guess there must be a similar simple way to get the size of the packet, right?

Comment: The only way to know the size of a packet received, is either to use a certain protocol (that defines the structure and sizes in the message data), or send the size in front of the message payload data.

Comment: does TCP support telling the packet size? Also, I want to get the packet size before calling `boost::thread t(session, sock);`

Comment: No, TCP is a transparent transport mechanism.

Comment: I managed to get this, it's `sock->available()`. How can this be explained?

Comment: @Luka `available()` returns the number of bytes available *at the moment* (in a kernel buffer) - you should not reach any conclusion based on this number. If "packet size" have some meaning at your application level, you should pass this size as a part of the application-level data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the application level, it is often far more useful to know the number of bytes currently available for reading, rather than the *packet* size.  The amount of data available for reading may be constructed from one or more TCP *segments*.  In the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), a TCP *segment* (Layer 4: Transport) may be constructed from one or more IP Layer *packets* (Layer 3: Network), and each *packet* may be constructed from one or more Ethernet *frames* (Layer 2: Data Link).

Therefore, I am going to assume the application is interested in knowing how many bytes to read, rather than knowing lower level details, such as the size of a packet.  There are a few solutions to this problem:

- Query the socket for how much data is available via [`socket::available()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/available/overload1.html), then allocate the buffer accordingly.

  ```
  std::vector<char> data(socket_.available());
  boost::asio::read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data));
  ```
- Use a class that Boost.Asio can grow in memory, such as [`boost::asio::streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html).  Some operations, such as [`boost::asio::read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload6.html) accept `streambuf` objects as their buffer and will allocate memory as is required for the operation.   However, a completion condition should be provided; otherwise, the operation will continue until the buffer is full.

  ```
  boost::asio::streambuf data;
  boost::asio::read(socket_, data,
                    boost::asio::transfer_at_least(socket_.available()));
  ```
- As [Igor R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255844/c-boost-asio-get-data-size#comment33850451_22255844) suggests in the comments, incorporate length as part of the communication protocol.  Check the Boost.Asio [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) for examples of communication protocols.  Focus on the protocol, not necessarily on the Boost.Asio [API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html).

  - In a fixed length protocol, a constant byte size is used to indicate message boundaries, such as in the Boost.Asio [Porthopper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.porthopper) example.  As the reader knows the size of the message, the reader can allocate a buffer in advance.
  - In a variable length protocol, such as the one used in the Boost.Asio [Chat](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.chat) example, a message is often divided into two parts: a header and a body.  One approach is to have a a fixed size header that contains various meta-information, such as the length of the body.  This allows an application to read a header into a fixed size buffer, extract the body length, allocate a buffer for the body, then read the body.

    ```
    // Read fixed header.
    std::vector<char> data(fixed_header_size);
    boost::asio::read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data));

    protocol::header header(data);
    network_to_local(header); // Handle endianess.

    // Read body.
    data.resize(header.body_length());
    boost::asio::read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data));  

    protocol::body body(data);
    network_to_local(body); // Handle endianess.
    ```

On the other hand, if I am mistaken, and you do need the [total length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Total_Length) of a packet, then one can use the [`basic_raw_socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_raw_socket.html).  Boost.Asio's [ICMP example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.icmp) demonstrates reading IPv4 packets from a socket, and extracting the header's field values.