# boost asio async_read: the read message adds to itself

Tags: c++, asynchronous, buffer, boost-asio, tcpserver

I use my PC as a server. The client sends messages like: "PART1:Part2", and the server performs the necessary actions. I use boost's asio for the server code.

```
    void start_read()
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, input_buffer_,
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    // When stream is received handle the message from the client
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = input_buffer_.data();
            std::string msgstr(boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs),
                               boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs) +
                               input_buffer_.size());

            std::vector<std::string> msgVector;
            boost::split(msgVector, msgstr, boost::is_any_of(":"));

            messageFromClient_ = msgVector[0];
            valueFromClient_ = msgVector[1];
};
```

Messages to the server are sent every second and the resulting msgstr looks like this:

```
PART1:part2a
PART1:part2bPART1:part2b
PART1:part2cPART1:part2cPART1:part2c
PART1:part2dPART1:part2dPART1:part2dPART1:part2d
```

This is not what I want. I do not want to include data from the previous buffer, i.e. I want this:

```
PART1:part2a
PART1:part2b
PART1:part2c
PART1:part2d
```

I understand that the problem most likely lies here:

```
            std::string msgstr(boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs),
                               boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs) +
                               input_buffer_.size());
```

However, I cannot find the correct code that would work in my case.

EDIT:
Tried to do this instead:

```
std::istream response_istream(&input_buffer_);
std::string msgstr;
response_istream >> msgstr;
```

The first three times, I get what I need, but then the message is multiplied. It is always like this:

```
PART1:part2a
PART1:part2b
PART1:part2c
PART1:part2dPART1:part2d
PART1:part2ePART1:part2e
PART1:part2fPART1:part2fPART1:part2fPART1:part2f
PART1:part2gPART1:part2g
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`streambuf::data()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/data.html) member-function returns buffers representing the input sequence.  To avoid accessing the data again, one can use the [`streambuf::consume()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/consume.html) member-function to remove characters from the beginning of the input sequence.  In this case, once data has been copied from `input_buffer_` to `msgstr`, the input sequence can be cleared with:

```cpp
input_buffer_.consume(input_buffer_.size());
```

---

Here is a complete minimal example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95ee1ead0520c45d) the behavior of `consume()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // Connect client and server sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, boost::bind(&noop));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), boost::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();

  // No-consuming case.
  { 
    std::cout << "Non-consuming example" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
      std::string data = "test";
      data += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);

      // Write to server.
      std::size_t bytes_transferred =
          write(client_socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));

      // Read from client.
      read(server_socket, streambuf, 
           boost::asio::transfer_exactly(bytes_transferred));

      // Print results.
      std::string read_data(
        boost::asio::buffers_begin(streambuf.data()),
        boost::asio::buffers_end(streambuf.data()));
      std::cout << "size: " << streambuf.size() << ", "
                << "read: " << read_data << std::endl;
    }
  }

  // Consuming case.
  { 
    std::cout << "Consuming example" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
      std::string data = "test";
      data += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);

      // Write to server.
      std::size_t bytes_transferred =
          write(client_socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));

      // Read from client.
      read(server_socket, streambuf, 
           boost::asio::transfer_exactly(bytes_transferred));

      // Print results.
      std::string read_data(
        boost::asio::buffers_begin(streambuf.data()),
        boost::asio::buffers_end(streambuf.data()));
      std::cout << "size: " << streambuf.size() << ", "
                << "read: " << read_data << std::endl;

      streambuf.consume(bytes_transferred);
    }
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
Non-consuming example
size: 5, read: test0
size: 10, read: test0test1
size: 15, read: test0test1test2
size: 20, read: test0test1test2test3
size: 25, read: test0test1test2test3test4
Consuming example
size: 5, read: test0
size: 5, read: test1
size: 5, read: test2
size: 5, read: test3
size: 5, read: test4
```

Notice how in the consuming case, the previous data is discarded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tanner. I have this now: `           boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = input_buffer_.data();`  `std::string msgstr(boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs),boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs) +input_buffer_.size());` `input_buffer_.consume(input_buffer_.size());` This makes it a problem as I showed in my text after edit, i.e. the first three times, the string is normal, but then it is like this: PART1:part2aPart1:part2a. Every now and then, I have three components in the string. Hm.. Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: Tanner, again thanks a lot for your help. This is very informative and useful. I think I know why it is happening. The client sends a message every second, and the server is supposed to do some manipulations as soon as the message is sent. But it takes time for server to do the manipulations, sometimes 2 seconds, sometimes 3. So, the buffer is getting accumulated with the messages sent from the client. Best regards,

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn TCP is a stream, and thus has no defined message boundary.  Hence, the code must be able to handle accumulated values and partial values.  For example, the sender could send "PART1:part2a" but a call to `handle_read()` only reads "PAR".  This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22291720/1053968) provides some references on how to handle this for fixed size or variable length application protocols.  Additionally, due to the payload size, disabling Nagle, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23871833/1053968), may increase performance.